# Pass data of array to react native view

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, fetch-api

I have a function that fetch the data from backend and map over the data and then add them to array
called `events_data`

```
function getvals() {

    return fetch('http://**********/users/timetable')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((output) => {
            addData(output, events_data);
        })


        .catch(error => console.log(error))

}

function addData(data, data2) {
    data.map((d) => {
        data2.push({
            title: d.name,
            startTime: genTimeBlock(d.day, d.start_time),
            endTime: genTimeBlock(d.day, d.end_time),
            location: d.location,
            extra_descriptions: [d.extra_descriptions],
        });
    });
}
```

So in my app view I want to pass `events_data` to `events` props:

```
 <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, padding: 30 }}>
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <TimeTableView
           scrollViewRef={this.scrollViewRef}
           events={// events.data will be passed here as array format //}**
           pivotTime={8}
           pivotDate={this.pivotDate}
           numberOfDays={this.numOfDays}
           onEventPress={}
           headerStyle={styles.headerStyle}
           formatDateHeader="dddd"
           locale="en"
          />
      </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

**Side note:**  the timetable view it is a third party package that accept array passed in porp   `events={}` and display its data in timetable format
so here I want to pass `events_data` array coming from  `function addData` and pass it to `events prop` in   `<TimeTableView>`

Comment: you never use state?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial ow to do that I'm beginner to react native. and I'm using class component. and the array is defined out side the class so how i set state to the array data from inside the class and then i can pass it to the app view easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getvals() {

    return fetch('http://**********/users/timetable')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((output) => {
            return addData(output, events_data); //<-- add a return statement.
        })


        .catch(error => console.log(error))

}
```

in your class component where you are calling the get Val function.

```
const data = getvals();
this.setState({ events: data });
```

then you can use this.state.events in your table.

Comment: i got this error  `The 'const' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files.` when i used `const data = getvals();`

Comment: function data () { }